# Русский текст при экспорте в Excel отображается не верно

Tags: javascript, excel

Мне нужно выгружать некоторую таблицу в Excel. Для этого я пользуюсь следующим кодом:

```
var excel = function(table, worksheetName) {
    var uri = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,';
    var template = '<html\
        xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"\
        xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel"\
        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">\
        <head>\
            <!--[if gte mso 9]>\
                <xml>\
                    <x:ExcelWorkbook>\
                        <x:ExcelWorksheets>\
                            <x:ExcelWorksheet>\
                                <x:Name>{worksheet}</x:Name>\
                                <x:WorksheetOptions>\
                                    <x:DisplayGridlines/>\
                                </x:WorksheetOptions>\
                            </x:ExcelWorksheet>\
                        </x:ExcelWorksheets>\
                    </x:ExcelWorkbook>\
                </xml>\
            <![endif]-->\
        </head>\
        <body>\
            <table>\
                {table}\
            </table>\
        </body>\
    </html>';

    var base64 = function(s) {
        return $window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(s)));
    };

    var format = function(s,c) {
        return s.replace(/{(\w+)}/g, function(m,p){
            return c[p];
        });
    };

    var ctx = {
        worksheet: worksheetName,
        table: table.innerHTML
    };

    var href = uri + base64(format(template, ctx));
    return href;
}
```

Если это имеет значение, вот оригинальный код: https://codepen.io/marco27384/pen/pboLyx

Проблема вот в чем - русский текст отображается вот так:

> %u0421%u0438%u0431%u0438%u0440%u0441%u043A%u0438%u0435%20%u043F%u0435%u043B%u044C%u043C%u0435%u043D%u0438%0A%0A%u0412%201979%20%u0433%20%u044F%20%u0437%u0430%u043A%u0430%u043D%u0447%u0438%u0432%u0430%u044E%20%u0438%u043D%u0441%u0442%u0438%u0442%u0443%u0442%2C%20%u0438%20%u0440%u0430%u0441%u043F%u0440%u0435%u0434%u0435%

Как это исправить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема оказалась до ужаса простой. Я экспериментировал с выгрузкой в эксель и в одно время у меня была функция `encode`, которой я обрабатывал текст перед выгрузкой.

Позже, функцию `encode` я удалил, но по прежнему пытался ее использовать:

```
...
encode(text)
...
```

Именно из за этого текст и превращался в кракозябры.